# Remove History from Android Activity navigation

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation, back

I'm creating an Android App with many Acitivities. I would like that the hardware Back Button is used to exit an App and not to go back on the previous activity.
How can I achieve that ? Thanks ;)

Comment: please see http://tips.androidhive.info/2013/10/how-to-clear-all-activity-stack-in-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [`android:noHistory="true"` to each one of your `<activity>` elements](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist). The activity will automatically be destroyed when the user navigates away from it by any means.

Note that this behavior may make you unpopular with users.

Comment: Thank your for the answer. I know about that feeling. The thing is that I have a Login Activity and when the user is logged in and he presses the back button, I don't want him to come back on the login activity...

Comment: @HubertSolecki: For an individual, special activity, like a login activity, using `noHistory` is reasonable. Your question suggests that you want this behavior for all of your "many Activities", and *that* is likely to be unpopular.

Answer (score 0):

Just override this onKeyDown method in your activity.

// Working for all API levels

```
@Override

  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

      moveTaskToBack(true);

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

  }
```